# Laravel Queue worker on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, queue, laravel-5

I'm running Laravel 5 on Heroku. I'm using the Laravel Queue for background tasks. What is/are the most reliable ways to listen to the queue and run it's jobs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** Deprecation notice

```
php artisan queue:work -h

--daemon    Run the worker in daemon mode (Deprecated)
```

Running `queue:work` spawns a daemon automatically. The flag is no longer required.

---

For me, it worked using Redis as the queue driver and setting up a queue `worker` process additionally to the `web` process.

My Procfile then looks like this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
```

I don't really know if this is the way one should go, but it works for now.

**Edit:**

Note, that you are starting up another dyno here, so if you are not using the free tier on Heroku it's double the price now.

Comment: Is the `--deamon` mode working well for you on Heroku?

Comment: @Till yes it does. what problems do you have with it?

Answer (score 11):

Set config var in heroku like this (Laravel 5.6):

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Or set config var in heroku like this (Laravel 5.7):

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

To start the worker dyno in case it is not running

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Procfile looks like this: Note: specify the driver you want to use after queue:work

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:restart && php artisan queue:work database --tries=3
```

To view messages from the worker

```
heroku logs --ps worker
```

To tail messages from the worker

```
heroku logs --tail --ps worker
```

Comment: Why do you specify `QUEUE_CONNECTION` if you pass it as parameter to `queue:work`?

Comment: Ah, I figured out, it is needed for `dispatch` calls in the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the **free** plan on Heroku quite easy to get the worker process running for processing your queued items

To make sure you have both the worker and web dynos running

```
heroku ps:scale
```

To start the worker dyno in case it is not running

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Proc file looks like this:

```
worker: php artisan queue:restart && php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

To view messages from the worker

```
heroku logs --ps worker
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found running the Queue Worker as a daemon [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#daemon-queue-worker) works well when used with supervisord [supervisor docs](http://supervisord.org/) which will watch the process and restart it if it should fail for any reason.

Laravel Forge supports this out of the box and provides you with a GUI to setup the daemon and supervisor tasks, if that's something you'd prefer